# spring load dynamically beans from xml which use property injection

Tags: java, xml, spring, applicationcontext, spring-bean

I need to load bean definitions from XML. The file is in a remote location (http) which is configured by properties. The properties should also be loaded from a remote location (a spring cloud config server)

constraints:

- Spring 4.3.14 (**not boot**)
- should be in runtime and **after** my properties already loaded
- beans defined in xml are referencing properties in context
- server URI (to fetch the xml from) should be in properties **and not** environment variable or profile depandant

The current setup I have works well when `MY_XML_URI` is passed as environment variable:

${SPRING_CONFIG_URI}/master/application-${spring.profiles.active}.properties

```
<import resource="${MY_XML_URI}/myBeans.xml"/>
```

And in the remote location, myBeans.xml with lots of beans e.g.

```
<bean name="mySpecialBean" class="com.example.MyGenericBean">
        <constructor-arg value="mySpecialBean"/>
        <constructor-arg value="${special.bean.config.expression}"/>
</bean>
```

However trouble starts when I want to get `MY_XML_URI` from the properties context, it doesn't resolve
…

I have tried several approaches e.g:

- java configuration class with `@ImportResource({"${xml.server.uri}"})` 
  but the properties are not loaded yet so it not converting to real value of `xml.server.uri` .

  ```
  @Configuration
  @ImportResource({"${xml.server.uri:http://localhost:8888}/myBeans.xml"})
  public class MyConfiguration {}
  ```
- expose dummy bean which fetch xml as resource and load the beans to parent applicationcontext - i must have it available to other beans dependant on those beans defined in xml. This solution was not injecting the properties context to my beans so failed to init them.

  ```
  @Configuration
  public class RiskConfig {

          @Value("${xml.server.uri}")
          private String xmlUri;

          @Autowired
          @Bean
          public Object myBean(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
                  Resource resource = applicationContext.getResource(xmlUri + "myBeans.xml");

  //              not working since its not loading the beans to the main context
  //              GenericApplicationContext genericApplicationContext = new GenericApplicationContext(applicationContext);
  //              XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(genericApplicationContext);
  //              reader.loadBeanDefinitions(resource);

                  AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
                  BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) factory;

                  XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(registry);
                  reader.loadBeanDefinitions(resource);

                  return new Object();
          }
  }
  ```

Finally - is there a way to load the beans from xml programmatically to parent application context (which is already exist) though they are injected with properties.

Comment: placeholders in `import` elements are only resolved from the system properties or the environment. Not from loaded property files. Loading property files and contexts isn't a multi pass operation, so what you want isn't possible. At least not possible without coding something up yourself.

Comment: @m-deinum i don't mind coding something, do you have any specific suggestion or some spring hook to implement for this ?

Comment: Did you manage to make this work? If so, would you mind providing an Answer below so others can benefit? Thanks.

Comment: @JamieBisotti couldn't find a way to do exactly as I wanted, programmatically or load the URI from the configuration. I kept the solution as written above where I set the remote URI, aka MY_XML_URI, as an environment variable. The deployment script prepares the env variables responsible to fetch the real value of  MY_XML_URI from our configuration server.